# Why does compiling a header file with constexpr array use so much memory?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a header file with an array of unsigned chars that holds some raw binary data:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <array>
extern __declspec(selectany) inline constexpr std::string_view bin_name = std::string_view("test.bin");
extern __declspec(selectany) inline constexpr int bin_size = 10812406;
extern __declspec(selectany) inline constexpr std::array<unsigned char, 10812406> bin_data = {...}
```

I have another header file that takes that array and writes it to a file:

```cpp
#include "_.h"
#include <fstream>
void write_file(std::string const outputDir = ".") {
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(outputDir + "/" + bin_name.data(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    file.write((const char*)& bin_data[0], bin_size);
    file.close();
}
```

And finally in main I just call the function to write the file:

```cpp
#include "_.h"

int main()
{
    write_file();
}
```

Trying to compile the above in Visual Studio, or directly using cl (`cl /Os /std:c++17 /Zc:externConstexpr main.cpp`) results in the compiler using more than 12 GB of memory!

[image: Compiler memory usage in Task Manager]

The `bin_data` is only around 10 MB in size, so the >12GB allocation by the compiler seems an overkill. More importantly, the actual size of the binary data I wanted to use is around 50 MB, however as you might have guessed, compiling that exceeds my systems 32GB of ram, thus I can't do that.

So my questions are:

- Why does the compiler need so much ram?
- What can I do to reduce that?
- Is this a bug?
- Is this behavior unique to vc++, or does the same happen in gcc/clang?

Comment: Do you have 10812406 items in that initializer? As far as I'm aware, compilers haven't optimized that and will create an AST node for each and every element. There was a [blog post](https://thephd.dev/embed-the-details) discussing this in the context of a proposal.

Comment: @chris that could explain things. Do you know any way around that?

Comment: simply don't put such large objects in your code, load it from a resource or a file instead

Comment: I added a link to a blog post on the topic. It covers some of the common workarounds people use, but it of course does argue for the necessity of the proposal to make this better via the language itself.

Comment: I have already compiled huge tables on MSVC. Instead of a `std::array<unsigned char, 10812406>`, have you tried the simpler `unsigned char bin_data[10812406] = {...};`

Comment: @prapin yes, and although not to the same extent, it also required a LOT of ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers don't tend to do well with large initializers since the go-to method of compiling an initializer is to make an AST node for each element.

There's [a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1040r6.html) to deal with this in the language directly that includes motivation and alternatives:

```
constexpr std::span<const std::byte> bin_data = std::embed("test.bin");
```

The author of this proposal also wrote [a blog post](https://thephd.dev/embed-the-details) to look at the current state of things and further argue for the proposal.

The alternatives aren't really *great*. One technique is to put the large initializer into its own translation unit to avoid recompiling it. However, that doesn't scale—your too-large initializer would need to be split up appropriately to cap the memory usage for any particular TU, and that still doesn't play well with parallelized builds.

Another technique is to encode the data within a string literal and then parse it to get the type you were looking for. The proposal mentions that MSVC doesn't allow large string literals, and I don't know whether that's changed in the past couple years. Regardless of whether the data file contains the string literal directly or is used to generate the string literal in a build step, it's not great.

Then there are the alternatives that perform better, but are  quite non-portable and might require significant effort and ugliness to make portable enough. This involves placing the data directly in a file that is linked to, with tools to make that feasible and symbols to access the data. These also remove the possibility of using the data in constant expressions.

All in all, I haven't come across an alternative that doesn't come with significant baggage. From a business perspective, I would quite honestly consider that supporting the standardization efforts of a good solution could be worth it in the long run. Contributing optimizations to compilers' handling of large initializers is another avenue, but certainly isn't a trivial task. Circle had some success as part of the blog post's benchmarks, but that doesn't mean it's easy to transfer the results to other compilers, and MSVC is off the table entirely there.

Comment: I did see that std::embed was proposed, though I heard the committee wasn't very thrilled about it. Since this wasn't standard, I thought I'd try to see what the problem is on my own. Well, now I understand :) The MSVC documentation states a limit of 64KB for string literals, though on my VS2022 anything larger than 16KB errors out ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Guiorgy, It looks like it's [progressing pretty smoothly](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/28). Do remember that current standardization is slower than pre-covid and that there's a huge backlog of papers to get through. Once March hits, we'll probably hear more about the February meeting.